# SSIS - do not allow if

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have an employee table with both Active and Terminated employees, one of my columns is work email. Terminated employees should have their personal emails listed and Active employees should have their work emails listed. However, the source system I am pulling the information from allows active employees to update their work email. So I have some active employees with their personal emails listed.

For my purposes, I need all active employees to have their work email listed. In SSIS, what would be the best approach to solving my issue?

```
Ex: 
Name      Status    Email
Bob       Act       bob@workdomain.com
Joey      Ter       joey234@yahoo.com
Randy     Act       randy23@hotmail.com
```

Here, since Randy is as Active employee should have an email ending with @workdomain.com but, in the source system I pulled data from Randy changed his email to be his personal. Randy's email should be: randy@workdomain.com

Comment: Please share sample data with current data and expected result.

Comment: @Pinwar13 please see edit

Comment: Why are you not handling this in your extract script?

Comment: @iamdave The source system only allows me to pull data through an excel file.

Comment: Are you loading into staging tables?  If so, load as is into them and then do your transformations using SQL scripts.  Also, how do your know what the work email will be?  If this held in another table?  If not, how can your be sure what the work email will be with names like `Mary-Kate O'Shea`?

Comment: You have a problem with your data source. If your data source has inaccurate information and you are able to do a lookup to correct it then do so. Otherwise, you need to find an accurate data source.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done like below (to avoid OLEDB transformation - row by row operation).

Load the data to 2 Staging tables (may be temporary tables):

Table#1. StageEmp:

```
Name      Status    Email
Bob       Act       bob@workdomain.com
Joey      Ter       joey234@yahoo.com
Randy     Act       randy23@hotmail.com
```

Table#2: CorrectEmail

```
Name      Email
Randy     randy23@hotmail.com
```

In **Execute SQL Task**:

```
Update s
SET s.email = c.email
FROM StageEmp s
Join CorrectEmail c
ON s.Name = c.Name
where s.status = 'Act'
AND s.email not like '%@workdomain.com'
```

You should use `key` column in place of `Name`.

Load the data of StageEmp to actual table or update directly to the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you have one Data Flow Task under which you have one Excel Source to fetch data from excel file. You can do this way -

```
1. Add one "Lookup" component and pass output of "Excel source" to it.
2. Edit "Lookup" component, and add second source of input to it from your existing table (where you have work email).
3. Join these two inputs to "Lookup" component on the basis of one of the key columns,
   so that in output you have two columns one email column from source and one email column from destination.
3. Add "Derived column" component and pass output of "Lookup" to it.
4. Edit "Derived Column", add new column and add expression to check whether email column has "@work-domain" or not.
   If yes, then source email else destination email.
```

Hope so i am able to explain.
[image]